# In flutter TextFormField I can't clear the value when using double.parse

Tags: flutter

I am creating a dialog that allows a user to make a payment and it subtracts it from their current balance.

So if their balance is $100 and they type $25 into the form field and hit submit the balance is now $75.

That all works. My problem is if I erase everything in the TextFormField and hit submit the $100 balance is now $98.

That's because when I erase the value the first character sticks in the value and I can't delete it by hitting the delete key.

When I print the value, hit the delete key, and look at the console it looks like this...

25.00

25.0

25.

25

2

No matter how many times I hit delete, the 2 won't erase.

I narrowed it down to double.parse being my problem. Here is the code:

````
   onChanged: (val){balance = debtBalance-double.parse(val);
   print(val);},```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because parse method fails when provided with empty or null value. It doesn't really make sense to parse an empty string anyways, so just use default value 0 in those cases.

```
balance = debtBalance - ((val ?? '').isEmpty ? 0 : double.parse(val));
```

This code snippet checks if new text value is empty, and if so it substracts 0 instead of parsing.

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much

Comment: Hi @StevenJReeves if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.